# Node.js/Socket.io web app works flawlessly and indefinitely locally but browser hangs when on Heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, socket.io, mlab

I have a Node.js web app that makes regular socket.io calls to a MongoDB backend (every 30 minutes). I can have this running for days no problem locally. I just recently deployed to Heroku (free, 1 Dyno, using MongoLab for DB) and everything starts up and works fine. However, when the updates start to roll in, I get numerous errors in the browser console that things didn't quite go right with the update and eventually (about 3 or 4 updates in) and invariably, the tab hangs at 30% CPU and 800MB RAM (when it normally has nominal CPU and about 300-400MB RAM at most).

I use a string of promises to ensure that the async DB update steps happen in perfect sequence and they always do locally. But the console.logs suggest that the app is running out of order, when should be impossible, i.e. the app moves on before a promise it depends on resolves. That would explain all the errors (e.g undefined variables etc.) Has anyone seen anything like this with their apps that could suggest where to start looking for a solution? This isn't a problem deploying the app or starting the app on Heroku like most of the troubleshooting questions I see. The app runs, attaches to the port and comes up in the browser with no errors. It's only after running for a bit that things go haywire. I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have a similar setup (nodejs/socketio/heroku/mongodb); am using MongoLab with Heroku and I have the exact same issue. The app works great locally, but runs VERY slowly on the free heroku dyno. I have to adjust my socket session loop to only tick like once a second because it can't handle normal speed, and still after like 5+ minutes of use it ends up hanging indefinitely until I refresh the page. 

I saw you posted this a couple years ago. Have you had any luck since then, or is this just a problem with Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell without seeing the connection code and error, but initially what comes to mind is setting the connectTimeoutMS and socketTimeoutMS options (typically we recommend 30 seconds, or 30000). We've seen a few issues where configuring the timeouts helps tremendously in connecting to Heroku- particularly after idling.

Please write us at support@mongolab.com if you still need help! We'll help find the cause.

Comment: I have the issue mentioned by the OP even when there is no idling. It runs great locally, then becomes super slow and reports inconsistent errors (due to long hang-ups) when I push and use Heroku/MongoLab dev URLs. It might be because we are using the free accounts maybe? However I'm afraid to upgrade if it's just a service provider problem.

Comment: When you say "it runs great locally" does that mean a local app with a local MongoDB or with a local app and a MongoLab database? It sounds like you may be able to isolate MongoLab issues by testing a local app connected to MongoLab. That said, we generally recommend hosting your application in the same datacenter as your database, so a good test would be to spin up an AWS instance from the same datacenter as your MongoLab database and try connecting that way. If you see no issues with this setup, you can reach out to the Heroku support team.

Comment: I already have ruled out MongoLab by completely disabling the database and the problem still persists on Heroku, but not locally; although it happens way more often when the database is wired up. In other words, it seems like a Heroku problem.

Comment: I'd recommend checking with the Heroku team, who can be reached here: https://help.heroku.com/.